# Processing: Where would I initialize a counter if it is changed in draw?

Tags: java, processing

```
Table t1;
import ddf.minim.*;
AudioPlayer player;
Minim minim;
int stickColR=0;
int stickColG=0;
int stickColB=0;
int counter=0;
//--------------
void setup(){
  size(1000,600);
  smooth();
  t1 = new Table(1000,600);
  t1.startGame();
  //sound player setup
  minim= new Minim(this);
  player=minim.loadFile("ballsound.mp3");

}
//--------------
void draw(){
  strokeWeight(10);
  stroke(255,0,0);
  fill(26, 218, 35);
  rect(0, 0, 1000, 600);
  fill(0);
  noStroke();
  ellipse(0, 0, 100, 100);
  ellipse(1000, 0, 100, 100);
  ellipse(0, 600, 100, 100);
  ellipse(1000, 600, 100, 100);
  t1.updatePos();  //calling the function to update the position of the balls
  t1.visualize();  // Function responsible for drawing the balls


}

//--------------
void mousePressed(){
  t1.mousePressed(mouseX-t1.x,mouseY-t1.y);
}
//--------------
void mouseReleased(){
  t1.mouseReleased(mouseX-t1.x,mouseY-t1.y);
}
//=============================
class Table{
  boolean GameIsOver=false;
  float drag = 0.99;
  float bounce = 0.4;
  float wallBounce = 0.3;
  float pushFactor = 0.4;
  float maxPush = 20;
  color[] ballColors = new color[]{color (255), color (216,7,17),color(17,242,225), color ( #45B4CE) , color ( #6A6347) , color (#E80909) ,color (#CEA9A9)};
  Ball[] balls;
  Ball selectedBall;
  int x,y,width,height;


  //--------------
  Table(int w, int h){
    width = w;
    height = h;
  }
  //--------------
  void startGame(){
    buildBalls(5);
  }
  //--------------
  void buildBalls(int count){
    balls = new Ball[2*count+1];
    int x_coor_red=600;
    int y_coor_red=300;
    int x_coor_green=626;
    int y_coor_green=313;
    for(int i=0;i<count;i++)
    {
      balls[i] = new Ball(x_coor_red, y_coor_red,i+1, this);
      x_coor_red+=26;
      y_coor_red-=13;
      if(i>=3)
      {
        x_coor_red-=26;
        y_coor_red+=26;
      }

    }

    for(int i=0;i<count;i++)
    {
      balls[count+i] = new Ball( x_coor_green, y_coor_green,i+2, this);
      x_coor_green+=26;
      y_coor_green+=13;
      if(i==1)
      {
        x_coor_green-=26;
        y_coor_green-=20;
      }
      if(i==2)
      {
        y_coor_green-=20;
      }
      if(i==3)
      {
        x_coor_green-=45;
      }
    }
    balls[2*count] = new Ball( 0.5*(width), 0.5*(height),0, this);
  }
  //--------------
  void updatePos(){
    //simulation
    for(int i=0;i<balls.length;i++)
      balls[i].update();

    //collision detection
    for(int i=0;i<balls.length;i++)
      for(int j=i+1;j<balls.length;j++)
        balls[i].collisionDetect(balls[j]);
  }
  //--------------
  void visualize(){
    translate(x,y);
    noStroke();

    //draw stick

    if(mousePressed && selectedBall!= null && (mouseX<=26+selectedBall.x || mouseX>26-selectedBall.x) && selectedBall.ballColor==color(255)){
      stickColR+=2;
      stickColB+=2;
      strokeWeight(4);

      stroke(stickColR, stickColG, stickColB);
      line ( mouseX , mouseY , mouseX + cos (atan2 ( mouseY -selectedBall.y , mouseX - selectedBall.x) )*300 , mouseY +  sin( atan2 ( mouseY - selectedBall.y , mouseX -selectedBall.x ))*300);
    }
    //drawing
    for(int i=0;i<balls.length;i++){
      balls[i].visualize();

      //Balls"disappearing" in corners
      if(balls[i].x<50 && (balls[i].y<50 || balls[i].y>550) || balls[i].x>950 &&(balls[i].y<50 || balls[i].y>550)){
      player.rewind();
      player.play();
       if(balls[i].ballColor==color(255))
       {
         textSize(25);
         text("Cue Ball Sunk. GAME OVER",350,560);
       }

       fill(0);
       ellipse(0,0,100,100);
       ellipse(1000, 0, 100, 100);
       ellipse(0, 600, 100, 100);
       ellipse(1000, 600, 100, 100);
       balls[i].x=1200;
       balls[i].y=0;
       counter++;
       if (balls[i].ballColor != 255 && counter>=3)
       {   
         textSize(25);
         text("YOU WIN", 350,560);
       }  
    }        
  }
  }
  //--------------
  float kineticEnergy(){
    float energy=0;
    for(int i=0;i<balls.length;i++)
      energy += mag( balls[i].vx, balls[i].vy );
    return energy;
  }
  //--------------
  void mousePressed(int mx, int my){
    for(int i=0;i<balls.length;i++)
      if( dist(balls[i].x,balls[i].y,mx,my) < balls[i].radius) {
        selectedBall = balls[i];
        break;
      }
  }
  //--------------
  void mouseReleased(int mx, int my){
    if(selectedBall != null){
      float px = (selectedBall.x-mx) * pushFactor;
      float py = (selectedBall.y-my) * pushFactor;
      float push = mag(px,py);
      stickColR=0;
      stickColB=0;
      if( push > maxPush ){
        px = maxPush*px/push;
        py = maxPush*py/push;
      }
      selectedBall.push(px,py);
    }
    selectedBall = null;
  }
}
class Ball{
  float x,y,vx,vy,radius,diameter;
  int type;
  Table table;
  color ballColor;
  //--------------
  Ball(float x, float y, int type, Table t){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.type = type;
    diameter = 26;
    radius = diameter/2;
    table = t;
    ballColor = table.ballColors[type];
  }
  //--------------
  void update(){
    vx *= table.drag;
    vy *= table.drag;

    x += vx;
    y += vy;

    wallBounce();
  }
  //--------------
  void wallBounce(){
    if(x<=radius){
      vx = -table.wallBounce*vx;
      x = radius;
      player.rewind();
      player.play();

    }
    if(x>=t1.width-radius){
      vx = -table.wallBounce*vx;
      x = table.width-radius;
      player.rewind();
      player.play();
    }
    if(y<=radius){
      vy = -table.wallBounce*vy;
      y = radius;
      player.rewind();
      player.play();
    }
    if(y>=t1.height-radius){
      vy = -table.wallBounce*vy;
      y = table.height-radius;
      player.rewind();
      player.play();
    }

  }
  //--------------
  void visualize(){
    fill(ballColor);
    stroke(0);
    strokeWeight(2);
    stroke(0);
    ellipse(x,y,diameter,diameter);
  }
  //--------------
  void push(float dx, float dy){
    vx += dx;
    vy += dy;
  }
  //--------------
  void collisionDetect(Ball b){
    float distance = dist(x,y,b.x,b.y);
    if( distance < diameter && (b.x>50 && (b.y>50 || b.y<550) || b.x<950 &&(b.y>50 || b.y<550))){
      float vxSum = 0.5*(vx + b.vx);
      float vySum = 0.5*(vy + b.vy);

      float forceMagnitude = ((b.x-x)*(vx-vxSum) + (b.y-y)*(vy-vySum));
      float xForce = 0.25*(x-b.x)*forceMagnitude/distance;
      float yForce = 0.25*(y-b.y)*forceMagnitude/distance;

      vx   = vx + table.bounce * xForce;
      vy   = vy + table.bounce * yForce; 
      b.vx = b.vx - table.bounce * xForce;
      b.vy = b.vy - table.bounce * yForce;

      b.x = x + (diameter+1)*(b.x-x)/distance;
      b.y = y + (diameter+1)*(b.y-y)/distance;

      player.rewind();
      player.play();
      }
    }
  }
```

Im making a pool game in processing and I'm almost done but I'm stuck here.  I want to add a counter that counts when a ball has been in the corner, then once the counter equals ten, the number of balls, it will display the winning message.  I think something is going wrong in that the counter is being reset each time since it's in draw? But I'm not sure where else to initialize it.  Btw, right now I just have it >= 3 so that I can quickly see if it's working.  Thanks all

Comment: I don't see you updating the counter anywhere.

Comment: Oh yeah sorry I got rid of that while I was trying to figure out where to put it.  I had counter++; after balls[i].y=0 in void visualize().

Comment: I don't understand that code, where is located the draw ? I see a declaration of table then a import ... that can't be in Java. To answer you, counter is use in `visualize` not `draw` , if you declare it before the loop (if you don't need it after the loop) or in Table to keep the value between to execution of `visualize` but for now, the code and the explanation are not enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

due to my low reputation, I have to show you my solution even though I think I haven't fixed all the bugs in your code.

I think your bug stated in the question has little relationship with the **counter** variable. I ran your code and found that you tried to hide the "disappeared" ball by changing coordinates. It means that "disappeared" balls can still be qualified to the if statement below, and as the result, value of **counter** will keep increasing.

```
//Balls"disappearing" in corners
if(balls[i].x<50 && (balls[i].y<50 || balls[i].y>550) || balls[i].x>950 &&(balls[i].y<50 || balls[i].y>550))
```

So you can add a boolean field to the **Ball** class

```
class Ball{
    float x,y,vx,vy,radius,diameter;
    int type;
    Table table;
    color ballColor;
    // add this variable.
    boolean disappeared = false;
    // your constructor, wallBounce(), push(), collisionDetect()
    void visualize(){
        // only draw the ball when it hasn't disappeared.
        if(!this.disappeared) {
            fill(ballColor);
            stroke(0);
            strokeWeight(2);
            stroke(0);
            ellipse(x,y,diameter,diameter);
        }  
    }
 }
```

and then use it to avoid double counting.

```
// other code in visualize()
if(!balls[i].disappeared) {
    counter++;
    balls[i].disappeared = true;
}
// other code
```

Comment: Ok I tried this and I think I'm implementing it wrong somewhere? I'll answer my question and post the code can you check it? It's just drawing them for a split second, making them disappear, and then saying you win.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Table t1;
import ddf.minim.*;
AudioPlayer player;
Minim minim;
int stickColR=0;
int stickColG=0;
int stickColB=0;
float counter;
boolean isAllIn = false;
//--------------
void setup() {
  counter=0;
  size(1000, 600);
  smooth();
  t1 = new Table(1000, 600);
  t1.startGame();
  //sound player setup
  minim= new Minim(this);
  player=minim.loadFile("ballsound.mp3");
}
//--------------
void draw() {
  strokeWeight(10);
  stroke(255, 0, 0);
  fill(26, 218, 35);
  rect(0, 0, 1000, 600);
  fill(0);
  noStroke();
  ellipse(0, 0, 100, 100);
  ellipse(1000, 0, 100, 100);
  ellipse(0, 600, 100, 100);
  ellipse(1000, 600, 100, 100);
  t1.updatePos();  //calling the function to update the position of the balls
  t1.visualize();  // Function responsible for drawing the balls
}

//--------------
void mousePressed() {
  t1.mousePressed(mouseX-t1.x, mouseY-t1.y);
}
//--------------
void mouseReleased() {
  t1.mouseReleased(mouseX-t1.x, mouseY-t1.y);
}
//=============================
class Table {
  float drag = 0.99;
  float bounce = 0.4;
  float wallBounce = 0.3;
  float pushFactor = 0.4;
  float maxPush = 20;
  color[] ballColors = new color[]{color (255), color (216, 7, 17), color(17, 242, 225), color ( #45B4CE), color ( #6A6347), color (#E80909), color (#CEA9A9)};
  Ball[] balls;
  Ball selectedBall;
  int x, y, width, height;


  //--------------
  Table(int w, int h) {
    width = w;
    height = h;
  }
  //--------------
  void startGame() {
    buildBalls(5);
  }

  void restart() {
    t1 = new Table(1000, 600);
    t1.startGame();
  }

  //--------------
  void buildBalls(int count) {
    balls = new Ball[2*count+1];
    int x_coor_red=600;
    int y_coor_red=300;
    int x_coor_green=626;
    int y_coor_green=313;
    for (int i=0; i<count; i++)
    {
      balls[i] = new Ball(x_coor_red, y_coor_red, i+1, this);
      x_coor_red+=26;
      y_coor_red-=13;
      if (i>=3)
      {
        x_coor_red-=26;
        y_coor_red+=26;
      }
    }

    for (int i=0; i<count; i++)
    {
      balls[count+i] = new Ball( x_coor_green, y_coor_green, i+2, this);
      x_coor_green+=26;
      y_coor_green+=13;
      if (i==1)
      {
        x_coor_green-=26;
        y_coor_green-=20;
      }
      if (i==2)
      {
        y_coor_green-=20;
      }
      if (i==3)
      {
        x_coor_green-=45;
      }
    }
    balls[2*count] = new Ball( 0.5*(width), 0.5*(height), 0, this);
  }
  //--------------
  void updatePos() {
    //simulation
    for (int i=0; i<balls.length; i++)
      balls[i].update();

    //collision detection
    for (int i=0; i<balls.length; i++)
      for (int j=i+1; j<balls.length; j++)
        balls[i].collisionDetect(balls[j]);
  }
  //--------------
  void visualize() {
    translate(x, y);
    noStroke();

    //draw stick

    if (mousePressed && selectedBall!= null && (mouseX<=26+selectedBall.x || mouseX>26-selectedBall.x) && selectedBall.ballColor==color(255)) {
      stickColR+=2;
      stickColB+=2;
      strokeWeight(4);

      stroke(stickColR, stickColG, stickColB);
      line ( mouseX, mouseY, mouseX + cos (atan2 ( mouseY -selectedBall.y, mouseX - selectedBall.x) )*300, mouseY +  sin( atan2 ( mouseY - selectedBall.y, mouseX -selectedBall.x ))*300);
    }
    //drawing
    for (int i=0; i<balls.length; i++) {
      balls[i].visualize();

      //Balls"disappearing" in corners
      if (balls[i].x<50 && (balls[i].y<50 || balls[i].y>550) || balls[i].x>950 &&(balls[i].y<50 || balls[i].y>550)) {

        player.rewind();
        player.play();
        if (balls[i].ballColor==color(255))
        {
          textSize(25);
          text("Cue Ball Sunk. GAME OVER.  Press any key to restart.", 170, 560);
          if (keyPressed == true) {
            t1.restart();
          }
        }
        /*
        fill(0);
         ellipse(0, 0, 100, 100);
         ellipse(1000, 0, 100, 100);
         ellipse(0, 600, 100, 100);
         ellipse(1000, 600, 100, 100);
         balls[i].x=1200;
         balls[i].y=0;
         */

        if (!balls[i].disappeared) {
          counter++;
          balls[i].disappeared=true;
        }


        if ( counter>=3) {
          textSize(25);
          text("YOU WIN.  Press any key to restart.", 300, 560);
          if (keyPressed == true) {
            t1.restart();
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  //--------------
  float kineticEnergy() {
    float energy=0;
    for (int i=0; i<balls.length; i++)
      energy += mag( balls[i].vx, balls[i].vy );
    return energy;
  }
  //--------------
  void mousePressed(int mx, int my) {
    for (int i=0; i<balls.length; i++)
      if ( dist(balls[i].x, balls[i].y, mx, my) < balls[i].radius) {
        selectedBall = balls[i];
        break;
      }
  }



  //--------------
  void mouseReleased(int mx, int my) {
    if (selectedBall != null) {
      float px = (selectedBall.x-mx) * pushFactor;
      float py = (selectedBall.y-my) * pushFactor;
      float push = mag(px, py);
      stickColR=0;
      stickColB=0;
      if ( push > maxPush ) {
        px = maxPush*px/push;
        py = maxPush*py/push;
      }
      selectedBall.push(px, py);
    }
    selectedBall = null;
  }
}
class Ball {
  boolean disappeared = false;
  float x, y, vx, vy, radius, diameter;
  int type;
  Table table;
  color ballColor;
  //--------------
  Ball(float x, float y, int type, Table t) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.type = type;
    diameter = 26;
    radius = diameter/2;
    table = t;
    ballColor = table.ballColors[type];
  }
  //--------------
  void update() {
    vx *= table.drag;
    vy *= table.drag;

    x += vx;
    y += vy;

    wallBounce();
  }
  //--------------
  void wallBounce() {
    if (x<=radius) {
      vx = -table.wallBounce*vx;
      x = radius;
      player.rewind();
      player.play();
    }
    if (x>=t1.width-radius) {
      vx = -table.wallBounce*vx;
      x = table.width-radius;
      player.rewind();
      player.play();
    }
    if (y<=radius) {
      vy = -table.wallBounce*vy;
      y = radius;
      player.rewind();
      player.play();
    }
    if (y>=t1.height-radius) {
      vy = -table.wallBounce*vy;
      y = table.height-radius;
      player.rewind();
      player.play();
    }
  }
  //--------------
  void visualize() {
    if (!this.disappeared) { 
      fill(ballColor);
      stroke(0);
      strokeWeight(2);
      stroke(0);
      ellipse(x, y, diameter, diameter);
    }
  }

  //--------------
  void push(float dx, float dy) {
    vx += dx;
    vy += dy;
  }
  //--------------
  void collisionDetect(Ball b) {
    float distance = dist(x, y, b.x, b.y);
    if ( distance < diameter && (b.x>50 && (b.y>50 || b.y<550) || b.x<950 &&(b.y>50 || b.y<550))) {
      float vxSum = 0.5*(vx + b.vx);
      float vySum = 0.5*(vy + b.vy);

      float forceMagnitude = ((b.x-x)*(vx-vxSum) + (b.y-y)*(vy-vySum));
      float xForce = 0.25*(x-b.x)*forceMagnitude/distance;
      float yForce = 0.25*(y-b.y)*forceMagnitude/distance;

      vx   = vx + table.bounce * xForce;
      vy   = vy + table.bounce * yForce; 
      b.vx = b.vx - table.bounce * xForce;
      b.vy = b.vy - table.bounce * yForce;

      b.x = x + (diameter+1)*(b.x-x)/distance;
      b.y = y + (diameter+1)*(b.y-y)/distance;

      player.rewind();
      player.play();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok so I actually got the counter working, but then it says the message at the bottom for only a split second.  Any thoughts?  I'll edit my code in answer to what my code currently is.

Comment: Nevermind, with some tweaking it is now working.  Thanks so much @ choasia for your help!!